# Is anyone working with webp images?

Tags: 7, media

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site with a prominent flexslider paragraph rotating images.  The image files sizes appear to improve quite a bit if I convert them to .webp format. My problem is that I cannot select and upload a .webp image into the paragraph.

I have gone into the Structure/paragraph bundles, selected the paragraph, manage field, and edited the Image field adding webp to the list of other image formats in the "allowed file extensions" field (currently "png, webp, jpg, gif"). Save, and double check to confirm webp in the list.

Now, when I head back to add content, select to add the new flexslider paragraph, the Image field shows all the acceptable parameters (max file size, max image dimensions, allowed file types) below the Image selection field, except webp is not listed as an allowed file type... the list it shows is "png jpg gif".

As a test, if I remove gif from the structure/paragraph bundle/manage field panel, then gif would also be removed from the add content/paragraph bundle/allowed file type list, so I'm on the right track there. But I don't understand why webp is being ignored?

Also, as another test, I used the Ckeditor IMCE to upload and select the .webp formatted image and display it in the body section. This worked as expected.